# List all dimension members filtering on dimension attribute value

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, msbi

I want to list out all cars from Dimension.Car which has a status `IsPremium = 1`  from cube.
And also, a separate list of all cars from Dimension.Car which has status `IsFourWeeler = 1`

Dimension has attributes as follows:
1. Car Code
2. Car Name
3. IsPremium 
4. IsFourWheeler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are different  hierachies (either attribute or user hierarchies) in the *same* dimension then you can use the function `EXISTS`.

Defined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144936.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The example they show is the same as your situation:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
  EXISTS(
    [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
 , {[Customer].[State-Province].&[CA]&[US]}
  ) ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

But you have

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[SomeMeasuresInCube] ON 0,
  EXISTS(
     [Dimension.Car].[Car].MEMBERS
  ,  [[Dimension.Car]].[IsPremium].[1]
  ) ON 1 
FROM [YourCube];
```

`NonEmpty` could also be your friend:

```
WITH SET [SpecialCars] AS
  NONEMPTY(
    [Dimension.Car].[Car].MEMBERS
  ,([[Dimension.Car]].[IsFourWheeler].[1])
  )  
SELECT 
  [Measures].[SomeMeasuresInCube] ON 0,
  [SpecialCars]     ON 1 
FROM [YourCube];
```